# What the proper razor ways to extract method to reusable?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a Login method inside LoginModel that need to reuse to SignupModel. The method trigger when success full signup. What layer that use in razor to reusable method. I come from WPF. WPF introduce Command design pattern to reusable method into several viewmodel. C# cant inherit multiple class, so far i thinking Command design pattern with delegate inside SignupModel. But with that way, it not loosecouple. Example in here [Web show example to reusable](https://www.christianfindlay.com/blog/c-delegates-with-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection)

LoginModel

```
private bool Authenticate()
{
  // Validate model state
  if (ModelState.IsValid is not true) return Page();
  // query database if found return true otherwise return false.
}
private IActionResult Login()
{
   List<Claim> claims = new()
   {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, this.EmailAddress)
   };

   ClaimsIdentity identities = new(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   ClaimsPrincipal principal = new(identities);

   AuthenticationProperties properties = new()
   {
     RedirectUri = "/dashboard"
   };

   return SignIn(principal, properties, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
  if (this.Authenticate() is not true) return Page();
  return this.Login();
}
```

Comment: The details of your question are not clear. In general, you reuse code by extracting it into a new class. Generally, you don't use inheritance, but instead you use composition. For example, you can use this new class by storing it as a private property reference in the class that needs it (see composition).